# Error while taking Transaction log backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have sceduled a Transaction log back up schedule. But the backup is not happening. The error in the logs is this:

```
Transaction Log Backup.Subplan_1,Error,0,ARCOTDB1\ARCOT_DB_INST1,Transaction 
Log Backup.Subplan_1,(Job outcome),,The job failed.  Unable to determine if the 
owner (ARCOT-DB1\Superuser) of job Transaction Log Backup.Subplan_1 has 
server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group
/user 'ARCOT-DB1\Superuser'<c/> error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] 
(Error 15404))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error code `0x534` means `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`. I would look at the account `ARCOT-DB1\Superuser` which is used to run the backup and check if it has enough permission on the database and transaction log.